# Table with multiple rows doesn't work with forms in HTML

Tags: html, forms, post, input

Basically, I have a table with inputs inside a form tag, that are required by user to fill in.

When I test it, the form is working, but only when there is one row in a table. With two an more rows, a required attribute is not working.

I've written a simple [example](https://jsfiddle.net/abzryko9/)

This works, click enter inside input field to see.

```
<form>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<br>
```

This doesn't work, click enter inside input field to see.

```
<form>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="surname" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Your two input fields have the same `name` attribute, have you tried using different values?

Comment: That's because forms with more than one text input aren't submitted by hitting enter. Try adding a submit button to both forms and you'll see it works fine.

Comment: Nice @j08691 example here https://jsfiddle.net/qb9ep6jf/

Comment: @j08691 Thank you for explanation. And also timothyclofford for example, it indeed works. Someone can write proper answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because forms with more than one text input aren't submitted by hitting enter. Try adding a submit button to both forms and you'll see it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, is that supposed to be two identical fields in the different cells (and one of them is just misspelled)? If so, that's likely your problem. If they are intended to be two separate fields, it should work, but I'd need to see a more real-world example.

Also, I'd highly recommend using CSS to format/style your form. If that sounds intimidating, try Bootstrap--it makes creating pretty forms extremely easy.

Comment: They are different fields and the problem is with submitting multiple inputs by hitting enter, like @j08691 pointed out.

Comment: For my own edification and education, please tell me how y'all knew it was an issue of pressing Enter. I don't see where Adam said or showed that.